# WCF customizing metadata publishing

Tags: wcf

I have a universal service hosted on IIS7 that accepts a Message and returns Message ( with Action="*"). This service still publishes meta for the clients.

This metadata is explicitly specified using LocationUrl property in ServiceMetadataBehavior.

We have a requirement that the metadata can change during lifetime of the service, so in essence metadata has a lifetime.

I tried adding IWsdlExportExtension to the service endpoint behavior, but the ExportEndpoint method only gets called once (when the service is loaded first time). Is there a way for me to invalidate the loaded metadata so that anytime there is a call for wsdl using HttpGet, the behavior gets called ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you are asking for (changing the published service definition at runtime) is not possible - you need to remove the requirement which specifies that the metadata can change over time.

Once you've published a service, the only reason the service specification should change is because the service has been upgraded.

You should look closer at the business requirement which is making this technical requirement necessary, and try to find another way to satisfy it (perhaps post in [programmers.stackexchange](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/)).  Perhaps you can have multiple services available, and switch between the services over time - but this is a bit of a stab in the dark without knowing the business requirement.

Answer (score 0):

No there is no way. Moreover if you needed you are up to your fully custom solution because this is out of scope of web services. Changing metadata means changing the service itself = its internal logic which always result in restarting the hosting process and publishing new metadata.

Comment: well, the service itself is just a facade for many other services( wcf and non wcf), and they come and go dynamically.

Comment: Ok, so is it a router? In such case you should route original WSDLs.

Comment: well its more like a service bus